# rails translated paths example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**routes.rb**

```
match "about/how_it_works" => "about#how_it_works", :as => "about_how_it_works", :via => :get
  match "about/we_are" => "about#we_are", :as => "about_we_are", :via => :get
  match "about/what_is" =>  "about#what_is", :as => "about_what_is", :via => :get
```

I read [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths) and changed my code.

new **routes.rb**

```
scope(path_names: { about_we_are: 'translated-about-we-are', about_what_is: 'translated-about-what-is' }) do
  resources :about, path: 'translated-about'
end
```

But when I enter localhost:3000/about/translated-about-we-are, I encounter no route matches error.Do you know how can handle with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've specified `path` for resources `about` your path becomes `translated-about/...`.  So you need to use:

```
http://localhost:3000/translated-about/translated-about-we-are
```

then you should not get the error.

You can check all the routes generated by issuing `rake routes` from within your application directory.